# Longtable notes

Tags: longtable, tablenotes

can someone please help me with adding the table notes in the following long table? I want the table notes underneath the bottom line of the table and have all information kept on one page.
Notes want to add: People who report living with a partner are classified as married. Third, employment status is composed of three categories: employed, unemployed, and not in the labor force. Students and retired people constitute the category of those who are not in the labor force. Lastly, household size measures the number of family members in the respondent’s household, which includes the respondents (and their spouse and/or children) themselves.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
% \usepackage[longnamesfirst,round]{natbib}

% \usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape}
% \usepackage{graphicx} 
% \usepackage{indentfirst}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{plain}
% \usepackage{afterpage}
% \bibliographystyle{apsr}
% \usepackage{theorem}
% \usepackage{multirow,dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{chngcntr}
% \usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
% \usepackage{float}
% \usepackage{graphicx}

% \usepackage[all]{nowidow}

% \usepackage{epigraph}
% \usepackage{fullwidth}
% \usepackage{fancyvrb} % Allows customization of verbatim environments
% \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}




\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\textheight}{22.8cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13mm} \addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}



% \DeclareMathOperator*{\rk}{rk}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\Card}{Card}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\Prob}{Prob}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\cov}{cov}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\var}{var}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var\,}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Post}{Post}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Pre}{Pre}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\post}{post}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\pre}{pre}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Mid}{Mid}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\MID}{MID}

% \setstretch{1.21}
\newcommand\thead[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \small
  % Setting chaption
  \captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=-6pt}
  % Spacing
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Add caption}
  \label{tab:addlabel}% 
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{longtable}{
      l
      S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
      S[table-format=1.3,minimum-decimal-digits=3]
      *2{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      c
      *4{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      *2{c}
    }
    \toprule
    Country
    & {\thead{Heavy}}
    & {\thead{Foreigner}}
    & {\thead{Female}}
    & {\thead{Parental\\Status}}
    & {\thead{Household\\Members}}
    & {\thead{Married}}
    & {\thead{Divorced/\\Seperated}}
    & {\thead{Single}}
    & {\thead{Widow}}
    & {\thead{Age}}
    & {\thead{Observations\enspace}} \\
    \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    Austria        & 0.39 & 0.027 & 0.56 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.1  & 0.18 & 0.1  & 48 & 2941 \\
    Belgium        & 0.37 & 0.066 & 0.52 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.7  & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.09 & 51 & 2785 \\
    Bulgaria       & 0.23 & 0.003 & 0.53 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.72 & 0.07 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 50 & 2827 \\
    Croatia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.11 & 47 & 1931 \\
    Cyprus         & 0.29 & 0.057 & 0.52 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.05 & 0.22 & 0.05 & 45 & 1465 \\
    Czechia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.08 & 45 & 2925 \\
    Denmark        & 0.6  & 0.02  & 0.51 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.64 & 0.1  & 0.16 & 0.09 & 53 & 2878 \\
    Estonia        & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.61 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 51 & 2815 \\
    Finland        & 0.42 & 0.019 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 2 & 0.57 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0.13 & 54 & 2870 \\
    France         & 0.38 & 0.059 & 0.55 & 0.39 & 2 & 0.6  & 0.12 & 0.19 & 0.09 & 50 & 2905 \\
    Germany        & 0.35 & 0.027 & 0.51 & 0.32 & 2 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 51 & 4304 \\
    Greece         & 0.25 & 0.016 & 0.52 & 0.4  & 3 & 0.62 & 0.07 & 0.24 & 0.08 & 47 & 2918 \\
    Hungary        & 0.21 & 0.004 & 0.59 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.11 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 49 & 2842 \\
    Ireland        & 0.37 & 0.09  & 0.55 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.04 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2771 \\
    Italy          & 0.32 & 0.01  & 0.56 & 0.51 & 3 & 0.71 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2842 \\
    Latvia         & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.57 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.07 & 44 & 2714 \\
    Lithuania      & 0.31 & 0.001 & 0.59 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.53 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.15 & 48 & 2866 \\
    Luxembourg     & 0.48 & 0.379 & 0.56 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.69 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 48 & 1414 \\
    Malta          & 0.28 & 0.023 & 0.6  & 0.48 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.2  & 0.09 & 52 & 1419 \\
    Netherlands    & 0.61 & 0.022 & 0.53 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.63 & 0.07 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 52 & 2864 \\
    Poland         & 0.27 & 0.003 & 0.61 & 0.45 & 3 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 48 & 2793 \\
    Portugal       & 0.21 & 0.016 & 0.56 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.62 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 49 & 2788 \\
    Romania        & 0.2  & 0     & 0.5  & 0.42 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.1  & 47 & 2754 \\
    Slovakia       & 0.3  & 0.008 & 0.58 & 0.5  & 3 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.11 & 48 & 2895 \\
    Slovenia       & 0.34 & 0.012 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 51 & 2783 \\
    Spain          & 0.29 & 0.06  & 0.52 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 48 & 2854 \\
    Sweden         & 0.62 & 0.026 & 0.47 & 0.29 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.07 & 56 & 2890 \\
    United Kingdom & 0.39 & 0.091 & 0.54 & 0.38 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.26 & 0.1  & 50 & 3710 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: A few remarks: you use `\begin{threeparttable}` yet you commented out the use of that package. The package `threeparttabe` lets you define table notes and places them underneath a table. In your example there is no information about the notes you want to use and where they should be in the table (what cell). You commented out a lot of packages, Are those to be included again as the table notes question is answered?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what kinds of "table notes" you want to create. E.g., are you looking to provide an overall legend? Or are they footnotes to provide additional information about the contents of certain cells?

Comment: Any news? Does any of answer solve your problem=Does no one worth to upvote it? Or even accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of selected answer)? BTW, as I see, so far you not accept any answer on your question!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided I made this example. As you notice I deleted almost all commented lines and added two packages:

1. `graphicx` to provide the `\rotatebox{angle}{text}` option - used to rotate the column headers and
2. `geometry` to define the dimensions of a paper more flexible

The resulting code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}     % can be replaces by the package threeparttablex for additional options
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow,dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=6pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % provied \rotatebox{angle}{text}

\usepackage[
    paper=letterpaper,
    margin={12mm,15mm},
    ]{geometry}     % adds flexibilty to define margins and paper dimensions

\newcommand\thead[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

    \begin{center}
%       \small
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \captionof{table}{An overview of domestic demography within the European Union \tnote{c}} 
            \label{tab:addlabel}% 
            \begin{tabular}{
                    l
                    S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
                    S[table-format=1.3,minimum-decimal-digits=3]
                    *2{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
                    c
                    *4{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
                    *2{c}
                }
                \toprule
                Country \tnote{a}
                & {\thead{Heavy}}
                & {\thead{Foreigner}}
                & {\thead{Female}}
                & {\thead{Parental\\Status}}
                & {\thead{Household\\Members}}
                & {\thead{Married}}
                & {\thead{Divorced/\\Seperated}}
                & {\thead{Single}}
                & {\thead{Widow}}
                & {\thead{Age}}
                & {\thead{Observations\enspace}} \\
                \midrule%\endhead
                Austria        & 0.39 & 0.027 & 0.56 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.1  & 0.18 & 0.1  & 48 & 2941 \\
                Belgium        & 0.37 & 0.066 & 0.52 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.7  & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.09 & 51 & 2785 \\
                Bulgaria \tnote{b}      & 0.23 & 0.003 & 0.53 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.72 & 0.07 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 50 & 2827 \\
                Croatia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.11 & 47 & 1931 \\
                Cyprus         & 0.29 & 0.057 & 0.52 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.05 & 0.22 & 0.05 & 45 & 1465 \\
                Czechia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.08 & 45 & 2925 \\
                Denmark        & 0.6  & 0.02  & 0.51 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.64 & 0.1  & 0.16 & 0.09 & 53 & 2878 \\
                Estonia        & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.61 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 51 & 2815 \\
                Finland        & 0.42 & 0.019 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 2 & 0.57 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0.13 & 54 & 2870 \\
                France         & 0.38 & 0.059 & 0.55 & 0.39 & 2 & 0.6  & 0.12 & 0.19 & 0.09 & 50 & 2905 \\
                Germany        & 0.35 & 0.027 & 0.51 & 0.32 & 2 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 51 & 4304 \\
                Greece         & 0.25 & 0.016 & 0.52 & 0.4  & 3 & 0.62 & 0.07 & 0.24 & 0.08 & 47 & 2918 \\
                Hungary        & 0.21 & 0.004 & 0.59 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.11 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 49 & 2842 \\
                Ireland        & 0.37 & 0.09  & 0.55 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.04 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2771 \\
                Italy          & 0.32 & 0.01  & 0.56 & 0.51 & 3 & 0.71 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2842 \\
                Latvia         & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.57 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.07 & 44 & 2714 \\
                Lithuania      & 0.31 & 0.001 & 0.59 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.53 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.15 & 48 & 2866 \\
                Luxembourg     & 0.48 & 0.379 & 0.56 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.69 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 48 & 1414 \\
                Malta          & 0.28 & 0.023 & 0.6  & 0.48 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.2  & 0.09 & 52 & 1419 \\
                Netherlands    & 0.61 & 0.022 & 0.53 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.63 & 0.07 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 52 & 2864 \\
                Poland         & 0.27 & 0.003 & 0.61 & 0.45 & 3 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 48 & 2793 \\
                Portugal       & 0.21 & 0.016 & 0.56 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.62 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 49 & 2788 \\
                Romania        & 0.2  & 0     & 0.5  & 0.42 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.1  & 47 & 2754 \\
                Slovakia       & 0.3  & 0.008 & 0.58 & 0.5  & 3 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.11 & 48 & 2895 \\
                Slovenia       & 0.34 & 0.012 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 51 & 2783 \\
                Spain          & 0.29 & 0.06  & 0.52 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 48 & 2854 \\
                Sweden         & 0.62 & 0.026 & 0.47 & 0.29 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.07 & 56 & 2890 \\
                United Kingdom & 0.39 & 0.091 & 0.54 & 0.38 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.26 & 0.1  & 50 & 3710 \\
                \bottomrule%\endfoot
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}[normal]
                \footnotesize
                \item[a] Present members of the European Union
                \item[b] Estimated information
                \item[c] Data obtained from Brussels
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{center}
        
    \end{document}
```

which provides the output:

[image: threeparttable with notes]

*Note:* rotating the headers saves space in the layout of the table and makes it better readable. So the landscape orientation and even `longtable` weren't needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

One way to add a list of notes in a `longtable` is to add a list inside merged cells.

In the example, a custom environment `TabNotes` is to enclose formatting of notes and simplify all necessary changes, if required. I also added a macro `\TN` for creating notes in cells.

You could consider two distinguished captions in order to indicate continuation of the same table on subsequent pages. It would need `\caption` inside the `longtable` environment, not outside. The additional macro `\header` is to avoid repeating the same long header twice.

The full code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\textheight}{22.8cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13mm} \addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}

\newcommand\thead[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

% Table notes and annotations
\newcommand\TN[1]{\rlap{\textsuperscript{\,#1}}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{TabNotes}{O{\linewidth}+b}{%
  \footnotesize
  \begin{minipage}{#1}
    \begin{description}[
        nosep, noitemsep,
        align=right, labelwidth=1.5em,
        parsep=-2pt,   % to squeeze space between lines 
      ]
      #2
    \end{description}
  \end{minipage}}{}

% Common header
\newcommand\header{%
  Country
  & {\thead{heavy}}
  & {\thead{foreigner}}
  & {\thead{female}}
  & {\thead{parental\\status}}
  & {\thead{household\\members}}
  & {\thead{married}}
  & {\thead{divorced/\\seperated}}
  & {\thead{single}}
  & {\thead{widow}}
  & {\thead{age}}
  & {\thead{observations\enspace}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \footnotesize
  % Setting chaption
  \captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=-6pt}
  % Spacing
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \centering
  \begin{longtable}{
      l
      S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
      S[table-format=1.3,minimum-decimal-digits=3]
      *2{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      c
      *4{S[table-format=1.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]}
      *2{c}
    }
    % The first header
    \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel} \\
    \toprule\header \\
    \midrule\endfirsthead
    % Subsequent headers
    \caption{Add caption (Continue)} \\ 
    \toprule\header \\
    \midrule\endhead
    % Subsequent footers
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{12}{l}{Continue o the next page ...}\endfoot
    % The last footer
    \bottomrule\addlinespace
    \multicolumn{12}{@{}l@{}}{%
      \begin{TabNotes}[0.7\linewidth]
        \item[$^{*}$] a short note for Austria
        \item[$^{**}$] a very very long note for Sweden
        \item[$^{\dag}$] another short not for Latvia as a dagger
        \item[$^{1}$] a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very note for Spain
        \item[$^{2}$] a very very very very very very very very very very very very very note for Sweden
        \end{TabNotes}%
      }
    \endlastfoot
    % Table body
    Austria\TN{*}     & 0.39 & 0.027 & 0.56 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.1  & 0.18 & 0.1  & 48 & 2941 \\
    Belgium           & 0.37 & 0.066 & 0.52 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.7  & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.09 & 51 & 2785 \\
    Bulgaria          & 0.23 & 0.003 & 0.53 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.72 & 0.07 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 50 & 2827 \\
    Croatia           & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.11 & 47 & 1931 \\
    Cyprus            & 0.29 & 0.057 & 0.52 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.05 & 0.22 & 0.05 & 45 & 1465 \\
    Czechia           & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.08 & 45 & 2925 \\
    Denmark           & 0.6  & 0.02  & 0.51 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.64 & 0.1  & 0.16 & 0.09 & 53 & 2878 \\
    Estonia           & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.61 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 51 & 2815 \\
    Finland           & 0.42 & 0.019 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 2 & 0.57 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0.13 & 54 & 2870 \\
    France            & 0.38 & 0.059 & 0.55 & 0.39 & 2 & 0.6  & 0.12 & 0.19 & 0.09 & 50 & 2905 \\
    Germany           & 0.35 & 0.027 & 0.51 & 0.32 & 2 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 51 & 4304 \\
    Greece            & 0.25 & 0.016 & 0.52 & 0.4  & 3 & 0.62 & 0.07 & 0.24 & 0.08 & 47 & 2918 \\
    Hungary           & 0.21 & 0.004 & 0.59 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.11 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 49 & 2842 \\
    Ireland           & 0.37 & 0.09  & 0.55 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.04 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2771 \\
    Italy             & 0.32 & 0.01  & 0.56 & 0.51 & 3 & 0.71 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2842 \\
    Latvia\TN{$\dag$} & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.57 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.07 & 44 & 2714 \\
    Lithuania         & 0.31 & 0.001 & 0.59 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.53 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.15 & 48 & 2866 \\
    Luxembourg        & 0.48 & 0.379 & 0.56 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.69 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 48 & 1414 \\
    Malta             & 0.28 & 0.023 & 0.6  & 0.48 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.2  & 0.09 & 52 & 1419 \\
    Netherlands       & 0.61 & 0.022 & 0.53 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.63 & 0.07 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 52 & 2864 \\
    Poland            & 0.27 & 0.003 & 0.61 & 0.45 & 3 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 48 & 2793 \\
    Portugal          & 0.21 & 0.016 & 0.56 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.62 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 49 & 2788 \\
    Romania           & 0.2  & 0     & 0.5  & 0.42 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.1  & 47 & 2754 \\
    Slovakia          & 0.3  & 0.008 & 0.58 & 0.5  & 3 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.11 & 48 & 2895 \\
    Slovenia          & 0.34 & 0.012 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 51 & 2783 \\
    Spain             & 0.29 & 0.06  & 0.52 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 48 & 2854 \\
    Sweden\TN{**}     & 0.62 & 0.026 & 0.47 & 0.29 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.07 & 56 & 2890 \\
    United Kingdom    & 0.39 & 0.091 & 0.54 & 0.38 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.26 & 0.1  & 50 & 3710 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I appreciated. But I want to keep all the information in the same table if it would be possible to do so. Is there any way this can be achieved? I will try the multicolumn code to see if it can work. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I tried the multicolumn code to see if it could work. But it only works for one sentence note and I have a long table note...Sorry for not being very specific when I first asked this

Comment: @Snow I made mistake in the code. I corrected it and notes will span across the table but this turnsout to be a workaround not necessarily an optimal solution, if you want to stick to a long table. If you want everything on the same page (_n the same table_ consider [alchemist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680013/31283)'s answer. Otherwise, if you want much easier interface and more compact code, consider [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680020/31283)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `longtable` I would rather use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package. Table code is simpler, notes (and remarks) you can add as table options (see MWE below). For more details about `tabularray` consult package documentation. However compilation is a bit longer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=25mm]{geometry}  % for defining of page layout

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\small}

\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Add caption},
  label = {tab:addlabel},
note{a} = {members of Europe Union},
note{b} = {some longer note},
                    ]{colspec = {@{} l S[table-format=1.2]  S[table-format=1.3]
                                    *2{S[table-format=1.2]} c
                                    *4{S[table-format=1.2]} *2{c}
                                 @{}},
                      row{1}  = {guard, m},
                          row{2-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt},
                      row{even[4]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                      rowhead = 1  
                     }
    \toprule
Country\TblrNote{a}
    & Heavy 
        & Foreigner
            & Female
                & {Parental\\Status}
                    & {Household\\Members}
                        & Married
                            & {Divorced/\\Seperated}
                                & Single
                                    & Widow
                                        & Age
                                            & Observation   \\
    \midrule
Austria        & 0.39 & 0.027 & 0.56 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.1  & 0.18 & 0.1  & 48 & 2941 \\
Belgium        & 0.37 & 0.066 & 0.52 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.7  & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.09 & 51 & 2785 \\
Bulgaria       & 0.23 & 0.003 & 0.53 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.72 & 0.07 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 50 & 2827 \\
Croatia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.11 & 47 & 1931 \\
Cyprus         & 0.29 & 0.057 & 0.52 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.05 & 0.22 & 0.05 & 45 & 1465 \\
Czechia        & 0.36 & 0.005 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.12 & 0.14 & 0.08 & 45 & 2925 \\
Denmark        & 0.6  & 0.02  & 0.51 & 0.33 & 2 & 0.64 & 0.1  & 0.16 & 0.09 & 53 & 2878 \\
Estonia        & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.61 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 51 & 2815 \\
Finland        & 0.42 & 0.019 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 2 & 0.57 & 0.13 & 0.17 & 0.13 & 54 & 2870 \\
France         & 0.38 & 0.059 & 0.55 & 0.39 & 2 & 0.6  & 0.12 & 0.19 & 0.09 & 50 & 2905 \\
Germany        & 0.35 & 0.027 & 0.51 & 0.32 & 2 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 51 & 4304 \\
Greece         & 0.25 & 0.016 & 0.52 & 0.4  & 3 & 0.62 & 0.07 & 0.24 & 0.08 & 47 & 2918 \\
Hungary        & 0.21 & 0.004 & 0.59 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.64 & 0.11 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 49 & 2842 \\
Ireland        & 0.37 & 0.09  & 0.55 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.04 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2771 \\
Italy          & 0.32 & 0.01  & 0.56 & 0.51 & 3 & 0.71 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.06 & 47 & 2842 \\
Latvia         & 0.41 & 0.006 & 0.57 & 0.49 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.07 & 44 & 2714 \\
Lithuania      & 0.31 & 0.001 & 0.59 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.53 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.15 & 48 & 2866 \\
Luxembourg     & 0.48 & 0.379 & 0.56 & 0.54 & 3 & 0.69 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 48 & 1414 \\
Malta          & 0.28 & 0.023 & 0.6  & 0.48 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.2  & 0.09 & 52 & 1419 \\
Netherlands    & 0.61 & 0.022 & 0.53 & 0.36 & 2 & 0.63 & 0.07 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 52 & 2864 \\
Poland         & 0.27 & 0.003 & 0.61 & 0.45 & 3 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 48 & 2793 \\
Portugal       & 0.21 & 0.016 & 0.56 & 0.42 & 3 & 0.62 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 49 & 2788 \\
Romania        & 0.2  & 0     & 0.5  & 0.42 & 3 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.1  & 47 & 2754 \\
Slovakia       & 0.3  & 0.008 & 0.58 & 0.5  & 3 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 0.14 & 0.11 & 48 & 2895 \\
Slovenia       & 0.34 & 0.012 & 0.57 & 0.46 & 3 & 0.67 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 51 & 2783 \\
Spain          & 0.29 & 0.06  & 0.52 & 0.44 & 3 & 0.68 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 48 & 2854 \\
Sweden         & 0.62 & 0.026 & 0.47 & 0.29 & 2 & 0.62 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.07 & 56 & 2890 \\
United Kingdom & 0.39 & 0.091 & 0.54 & 0.38 & 2 & 0.55 & 0.09 & 0.26 & 0.1  & 50 & 3710 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I we bit change appearance table body. If you not liked, than in table preamble delete rows

```
                          row{2-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt},
                      row{even[4]} = {abovesep=1ex},
```